# Flower is shedding leaves

Tags: houseplants, plant-care, leaves

My flower is shedding leaves.

I have my flower for 6 years.
My flower is next to the heater (new place after moving). It is bright. I water it once a week.

What can I do?

Comment: Which flower? What is the present state of the plant? Some pictures would help...

Comment: Please add a photo if you do not know the name of your plant.